# Lazy Load and ajax calls issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, lazy-loading, chunks

I want to separate a list of 30 articles, into chunks of 5.

For this purpose, I wrote the following code:

```
private static function makeChunk($array = array(), $howMany = 5) {
    $shortChunked = array_chunk($array, $howMany);
    $count = count($shortChunked);      
    $html = '';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($shortChunked as $key => $chunk) :
        $class = '';

        if ($key == 0)
            $class = ' first active';

        if ($key == ($count - 1) && $count>1)
            $class = ' last';

        $html .= '<div class="my-chunk chunk'.$class.'">';

        foreach($chunk as $article) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                $img = '<img class="img-responsive" src="' . $article['image'] . '" alt="' . $article['imageAlt'] . '" />';
            } else {
                $img = '<img class="img-tab-ll img-responsive" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/imageLoading.gif" data-src="' . $article['image'] . '" alt="' . $article['imageAlt'] . '" />';
            }

        }

        $html .= '</div>';  
    $i++;
    endforeach;

    return $html;
}
```

This is working just fine, but Im considering also lazy loading the first chunk.

I noticed that if I also lazy load the first chunk, images are not showing up, unless I press the button to load the next series (next chunk), so it seems to me that Im missing something related to ajax/lazyload.

Any advises?